# What's the deal with rings in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been collecting a lot of valuable rings that I'd like to just sell, but I'm not sure if there's value in holding onto some of them.

This is what I understand:

- You can only have one ring equipped at a time
- You can enchant rings just like armor and weapons

Are all rings created equal for the purposes of enchanting? Or are certain combinations of gems and metals better to keep for enchanting rather than selling?

Comment: If you're holding one when you get hit, you won't die, it'll just fly out.  It helps to get Tails...  um, wait, what game were we talking about again?

Comment: The Elder Scrolls: Skyward Sonic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can enchant rings to increase the overall value of them while also increasing your enchanting skill. The better the metals, the better the prices too. However enchantments are the same no matter the materials of the rings (enchantments are only affected by the soul gem used and your skill, you could use potions too).

I also find it crappy you can only wear one ring, but thinking about it, being able to use rings on every finger would make the player too overpowered.

Also, there are unique rings if you are a collector. :)

Comment: Well, you did get 2 in past elderscrolls games.

Comment: I havent played the past TES games, do you had the chance to wear enchanted armor pieces, masks and amulets? Anyways, I wont be surprised to find later a mod that makes you able to wear one ring on the other hand, so PC users, lets just wait P:

Comment: Yup. Oblivion had all that.

Comment: Yeah, you could surely mod that in, but I feel like it will be a balance issue. The choice to allow only one is for balancing purposes. Adding another ring when you have 100 Enchanting gives you a huge boost to an arbitrary stat.

Comment: ohh morrowind... the game where you could equip each piece of armor separately: a hat, amulet, robe, armor, shirt, pants, greaves, Left and Right Pauldrons, left and right gauntlets, boots and shoes all at the same time. and yes, even two rings at the same time

Comment: @Skizzlefrits yeah but finding a matching set was a pain. "What do you mean the entire city is sold out of left pauldrons? Is there some new fad to just wear a left one?"

Comment: by pain do you mean a feat of awesomeness that you can brag to your friends about?